# How can I do a Transparent and Fixed Footer with Social Media Icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a website for my band, but I cannot solve this problem. So, to put you in context, I have a footer that I want to be fixed all the time in the website. So If you want to scroll down the page, even in the top of the page you will be able to see the footer (the footer will be social media icons).

So my main problem now is that I want to have 3 different parts in my page:
1. The nav bar that will be displayed at the top of the page (if it is fixed as well as the footer, would be excellent)
2. My main/head part that will be displayed, for example, images from a gallery.
3. The footer part that I want to be fixed and will be displayed social media icons (in total 4: IG, YT, Spotify, Apple Music).

So as you can see in the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyjg6.jpg

The main problem is that the footer in the bottom is collapsing the images I want to display in this page of the website. So I want to have this footer always fixed in order to not collapse the images. Does anyone know how to code that? I'd totally appreciate :D

This is the coding I'm using for the footer section:

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 99%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

.media {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.media i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.media:hover i {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.grow {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.grow:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="fa">
    <a class="media" href="https://www.instagram.com/massaviu/" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram grow" style="color: #E1306C"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCh1_-QpgzIdG-3QfCMfZi6w" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-youtube grow" style="color: #FF0000"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/0du3FPmKtQ8vfsmGYVzdFY" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-spotify grow" style="color: #1DB954"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="media" href="https://music.apple.com/us/artist/massaviu/1378812000" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-apple grow" style="color:  #A3AAAE"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: The nature of a fixed element allows it to be covering items like you are having happen here. Is there a chance you would accept an answer of using smaller icons instead of the larger ones? this is the way to get rid of the overlap. Otherwise, you could change up the position a little bit more so it's always beneath the photos, but this is taking away from the look I believe you are going for

Comment: It's fine, I already solve it and I will not be fixing the footer or the nav bar, too complicated for me to not collapsing with the images... Thanks, tho. :D

Comment: Sounds good, glad you got it worked out. You could still float the SM icons, but I would just float a div fixed like that rather than the footer. Footers are normally the bottom of the page with links